# Why do I get 0 results from a pySpark groupby over a column generated with a window?

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, databricks

I'm analyzing train passages in pySpark. I'm wondering why I get no results from a simple group by over a column that just contains a number generated by a window.

My pipeline code is as follows. I simplified to the relevant columns.

```
df_messages = spark.read.table("xxx.some_table")
  .withColumn('sourceTimeDT', f.from_unixtime(f.col('sourceTime')/1000, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
  .withColumn('ms', f.col('sourceTime') % 1000)
  .withColumn("rank", f.row_number().over(w.Window.orderBy(f.col('partId').asc(),
                                                           f.col('move_startsYMDHMS').asc(), 
                                                           f.col('ms').asc(),
                                                           f.col('msg_order').asc())))

location1_messages = (
  df_messages.filter("partId IN ('BRFHB', 'BROUB', 'BRZAB', 'BRBEB')")
             .orderBy("sourceTimeDT", "ms")
)

# processing of the messages in a few steps:

location1_messages_proc = (
  location1_messages
     # rank is a proxy in this case to order only on date time, not on location name as well:
    .withColumn("location1_rank", 
                f.row_number().over(w.Window.orderBy(f.col('sourceTimeDT').asc(),
                                                     f.col('ms').asc())))
    # we detect the start of a train passage by the change of the S1 status: (we'll consider all message between two S1 statusses as one potential train passage sequence.)
    .withColumn('prev_message', 
                f.lead(f.col('message_value'), -1, 'NA').over(w.Window.orderBy(f.col('location1_rank'))))
    # ... (detection of message sequences)
)

location1_messages_proc2 = (
  location1_messages_proc.withColumn('next1_partId', 
                                     f.lead(f.col('partId'), 1, 'NA').over(w.Window.orderBy(f.col('location1_rank'))))
  # ... extra logic for detecting sequences ...
)

location1_messages_proc3 = (
  location1_messages_proc2.withColumn("is_passage_start", 
                                  f.when(f.col("no_longer_free_on_other_bridge")=="start", 1).otherwise(0))
                      # The train passage ID, on which we'll do a group by later:
                      .withColumn("passage_id", 
                                  f.sum("is_passage_start").over(w.Window.orderBy(f.col("location1_rank"))))
)
```

`display(location1_messages_proc3)` shows the following:

| partId | sourceTimeDT | ... | passage_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| BRBEB | 2022-03-17 16:24 | ... | 3724 |
| BRBEB | ... | ... | 3724 |
| BRBEB | 2022-03-17 16:28 | ... | 3724 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

But the following group by code returns no results (??):

```
train_passage_first_and_last_message_times = (
  location1_messages_proc3.groupby("passage_id")
                      .agg(f.min(f.col("sourceTimeDT")).alias("first_message_time"), 
                           f.max(f.col("sourceTimeDT")).alias("last_message_time"))
)
display(train_passage_first_and_last_message_times)
```

I'd expect 1 result line, with first_message_time = 2022-03-17 16:24 and last_message_time = 2022-03-17 16:28, but I get 0 results back.

Does anyone understand why this doesn't happen?

I *do* get results with this though:

```
display(location1_messages_proc3.filter("passage_id == 3724"))
```

But not with this:

```
display(
  location1_messages_proc3.filter("passage_id == 3724")
                    .groupby("passage_id")
                    .agg(f.min(f.col("sourceTimeDT")).alias("first_message_time"), 
                         f.max(f.col("sourceTimeDT")).alias("last_message_time"))
)
```

So it must be due to the grouping or the way the column passage_id has been created.
(Or, as last option, a bug in pySpark.)

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: a reproducible example would be nice

Comment: Hey @ScootCork. Sorry, I can't share the code to enable reproduction, it's company-owned, I'm making an extension. Making a reproducible example from another dataset is hard, since I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried to describe everything well that I think is relevant. I'll try some experiments on my side. But I hope some clever guy/girl will look at it and say "of course, you just made mistake X." :-)